# how to send parameter from.aspx page to.cs file[in #eval method in gridview]

Tags: asp.net

in my gridview item template filed i am calling an method  **CheckValue**

```
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# CheckValue(Eval("Imagespath")+","+Eval("Imagesname")%>'>
            </asp:Label>


protected string CheckValue(string strValue1,string strValue2)
    {
        if (strValue1=="1")
        {
            return "No Record Found";
        }
        else
        {
            return "No Record Found";
        }
    }
```

when  i run my page i get errorin my .aspx page

**Text='<%# CheckValue(Eval("Imagespath")+","+Eval("Imagesname")%>'>**

is there any way i can send my value  CheckValue method which isa .cs file how can i send 2 paremeter from.aspx page
 can anu one tell me the syntax for it

thank you

Comment: have you tried with Bind instad on Eval. read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there... try this:

```
Text='<%# CheckValue(Eval("Imagespath").ToString(), Eval("Imagesname").ToString()) %>'
```

You don't need to add the +","+ as if you were concatenating a string (you aren't), and you do need to call ToString() on the Evals so it matches the parameter types your CheckValue method expects.